# How to save date and day into separate array without sundays?

Tags: php

I am trying to save a series of five dates into an array to be called. The date has no range since it is taking the current date to start with.

I would like to save without any Sundays as delivery is not an option for Sunday in my case. I am saving both dates and day in separate arrays.

```
$date = new DateTime("+ 1 day", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Thailand') );

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $date->modify("+1 weekday");
    $delivery_dates[] = $date->format("m/d/Y");
    $delivery_days[] = $date->format("l, d F Y");
}
```

At the moment, I am getting the following -

Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday (inclusive of the dates for each day in d F Y format)

Is there a way I can get the following -

Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday (inclusive of the dates for each day in d F Y format)?

For every Sunday I would like to +1 day so it makes an available day for delivery, on Monday.

I have used the following -

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $date->modify("+1 weekday");
    if ($date->format("N") !== 7 {
       $delivery_dates[] = $date->format("m/d/Y");
       $delivery_days[] = $date->format("l, d F Y");
    }
}
```

The codes above still display Sunday.

Comment: `$date->format("N") !== 7` - this will _always_ be true; you are doing a _strict_ comparison of two values of different types here. `date` will always return a _string_ value, even if it might “look” like a number.

Comment: Doesn't this all depend on what day you run it?  Do you just want to take today and find the next Monday and start from there?

Comment: That got me thinking.... Yes, I am trying to process by current date/day and omitting Sunday in the next 5 days.

Comment: So if today is Friday you want to add to the arrays: Friday, Saturday, Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday?

Comment: You may want to check out the library [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison), as there you have some helper methods for dates like `::isSunday()`.

Comment: Following what @misorude says: you can force *data types* to be equal like so: `if ((int)$date->format("N") !== 7) {`  ... Also you must remember to close your `if` statement (see the new `)` before the `{`)

Comment: @Martin in such a case I’d rather force the `7` to be `"7"` though ;-) (Or forgo strict comparison to begin with, it doesn’t add much benefit here in the first place.)

Comment: @misorude I totally sympathise with your route but PHP FIG holds that strict comparison should be used as much as possible; and I've always found it easier to run numerical rather than string comparisons (with regards to coding and maintenance). But really there's not a lot in it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $from = '2018-10-10';
    $to = '2018-12-10';
    $start = new \DateTime($from);
    $end   = new \DateTime($to);
    $interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'); // 1 day === P1D, 5 month and 5 years === P5M5Y
    $period   = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end); // A date period allows iteration over a set of dates and times, recurring at regular intervals, over a given period.
    // new \DatePeriod(10-10-2010, 5, 30-10-2010) ===> [10-10-2010, 15-10-2010, 20-10-2010, 25-10-2010, 30-10-2010]

    $result = [];

    foreach ($period as $day) {
        if (! in_array($day->format('w'), [0, 6])) { // check every date in period, ->format('w'): w - number of day; Monday = 1 or 7 (depends on wat day declared first)
            $result['date'][] = $day->format("m/d/Y");
            $result['day'][] = $day->format("l, d F Y");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), one way to implement is to generate the range with the help of a while-loop, and only add a date if it is not a Sunday, while ensuring that you'll get the required amount of days, in your case, 5.

```
/**
 * @param int $amount
 * @return Carbon[]
 */
public function getDeliveryDates($amount = 5): array
{
    $days = [];
    $current = Carbon::today();

    while (\count($days) < $amount) {
        $day = clone $current; // addDay works on instance, cloning it
        $day->addDay();
        $current = $day; // setting current to current day, so that it will iterate
        if ($current->isSunday()) {
            continue;
        }

        $days[] = $current;
    }

    return $days;
}
```

Then you can just format your date. If you still want two arrays with the info, you just need to iterate over the generated array:

```
$formattedDates = [];
$formattedDays = [];
foreach (getDeliveryDates() as $date) {
    $formattedDates[] = $date->format('m/d/Y');
    $formattedDays[] = $date->format('l, d F Y');
}
```

Comment: What does the slash in front of the function call do?  I've never seen that syntax in PHP.

Comment: @dmikester1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229086/what-does-the-prefix-do-for-certain-in-built-php-functions/53229087#53229087